# How to install `requests` module for `python3`?

Tags: 14.04, python, python3, pip

I wanted to download [Requests: HTTP for Humans](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module for `python3`. So I started with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install requests --upgrade
```

There were no errors.
However, when I try to import module, there are some errors:

```
enedil@VirtualBox:~/hacking$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2195, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 12, in <module>
    from http.client import HTTPConnection as _HTTPConnection, HTTPException
ImportError: No module named 'http.client'; 'http' is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 14, in <module>
    from httplib import HTTPConnection as _HTTPConnection, HTTPException
ImportError: No module named 'httplib'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2195, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
ImportError: No module named 'http.client'; 'http' is not a package

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2195, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 12, in <module>
    from http.client import HTTPConnection as _HTTPConnection, HTTPException
ImportError: No module named 'http.client'; 'http' is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 14, in <module>
    from httplib import HTTPConnection as _HTTPConnection, HTTPException
ImportError: No module named 'httplib'
```

So, how to install `requests` module for `python3` on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Why not `apt-get install python3-requests`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For 14.04, you just need to install [python3-requests](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-requests):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-requests
```

Comment: Now I have installed `requests`. But still it does not work. I'm getting exception errors: `Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined`

Comment: Are you able to run a simple `python3 -c "import requests"`

Comment: Still the same exception.

Comment: Try to remove what you partially installed in `/usr/local` with `sudo pip3 uninstall requests`

Comment: I simply rebooted system (was on VM so it was fast) and it works.